# Independant Two-Samples t-test with N > 30

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, normality-assumption

I have two groups of data (N > 30 in each group). I want to know if the two groups differ from each other. So I thought about making an independent t-test. But then I remembered that the groups must be normally distributed in order to perform a t-test. So I performed a Shapiro test and it appears that both groups are not normally distributed.

My question is: Am I still allowed to perform a t-test knowing that my groups are not normally distributed and that I have N > 30 in each group?

Thank you for your time.

Edit: When I do a QQ-plot on R with package ggpubr, both groups look like this (group 1 first, then group 2):
[image: This is the QQ-plot for the first group.]

[image]

It seems that there are some flat "levels" in both cases.

Here are the histograms (group 1 first, then group 2):
[image]

[image]

Comment: [Formal testing of normality is less helpful than one might hope.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless)

Comment: Seeing the QQ plots, are the histograms trimodal?

Comment: @Dave No I don't think the histograms are trimodal. I also added them. I checked the link you posted above. According to what I could read, it really depends on how your data look like, right? In my case, I think my data are quite far away from "almost normally distributed", meaning that t-test is a no-go?

Comment: Kontroll seems to have a mode around 800, another around 120, and another around 150; Versuch appears to have a model around 100, a model around 120, and a model around 160. // Perhaps the t-test is a no-go. Some people argue that we should default to the Wilcoxon Mann-Whitney U test, `wilcox.test` in R, so we do not have to address issues like this.

Comment: The shapes of those histograms make me wonder if a focus on the means using a t-test is going to capture all (or any) of the possibly interesting features of the groups.

Comment: @MichaelLew raises a good point that I often think but rarely see discussed. You can find plenty written about the t0test being robust to deviations from normality, and you can find comments suggesting to [go with Wilcoxon no matter what](https://twitter.com/f2harrell/status/1379848069085327361), since deviations from normality can be impactful and the Wilcoxon test is nearly as good as the t-test, even when the t-test assumptions hold, but there is little about how, if there are deviations from normality, differences in the mean might not be all that interests us.

Answer (score 3):

Here are fictitious data, sampled using R, somewhat similar to your data.

```
set.seed(1234)
x1 = c(rnorm(50,100, 2), rnorm(140, 125, 5), rnorm(40,155,3))
x2 = c(rnorm(50,105, 2), rnorm(150, 125, 5), rnorm(40,156,2))
summary(x1); length(x1); sd(x1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  95.31  118.30  124.70  125.01  131.94  163.76 
[1] 230
[1] 18.12978
summary(x2); length(x2); sd(x2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  98.53  117.40  124.34  125.83  130.64  160.12 
[1] 240
[1] 16.01616

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 hist(x1, br=5, col="skyblue2")
 hist(x2, br=5, col="skyblue2")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

```
x = c(x1,x2)
g = c(rep(1,230),rep(2,240))
boxplot(x~g, notch=T, col="skyblue2", horizontal=T)
```

Notches in the sides of boxplots are nonparametric CIs roughly
calibrated so that overlapping CIs suggest no significant difference
in location.

[image]

Shapes of the samples are similar, so a nonparametric 2-sample
Wilcoxon rank sum test should test for a significant difference
in location. The P-value $0.75 > 0.05 = 5\%$ indicates no significant
difference.

```
wilcox.test(x~g)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test 
        with continuity correction

data:  x by g
W = 27134, p-value = 0.7518
alternative hypothesis: 
 true location shift is not equal to 0
```

If these were the actual data, I would stop here. Of course,
your data may show different results.

For the reasons you mention, I would not trust a 2-sample t test
to give reliable results, but for such large sample sizes
its P-value may be roughly correct. Again, no indication of
a significant difference.

```
t.test(x~g, var.eq=T)  # pooled t test

        Two Sample t-test

data:  x by g
t = -0.51847, df = 468, p-value = 0.6044
alternative hypothesis: 
 true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -3.914830  2.280273
sample estimates:
mean in group 1 mean in group 2 
       125.0149        125.8322
```

Even though I would not trust a pooled t statistic to have
Student's t distribution in these circumstances, the t statistic
does seem a reasonable way to measure a difference between means
of the two samples.

A permutation test using the pooled t statistic as metric,
does not find a significant difference, its P-value is
about the same as for the pooled t test. No significant difference.

```
set.seed(2021)
t.obs = t.test(x~g, var.eq=T)$stat
t.prm = replicate(10^5, t.test(x~sample(g), var.eq=T)$stat)
mean(abs(t.prm) > abs(t.obs))
[1] 0.6094  # P-value of simulated permutation test

hdr = "Simulated Permutation Dist'n"
hist(t.prm, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
abline(v = c(t.obs,-t.obs), col="red", lwd=2)
```

[image]